# Метод equals() в Java

Tags: java

Как правильно переопределить метод `equals()` в Java?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Приведу пример, по которому все будет понятно, также не надо забывать, что при переопределении метода equals() необходимо переопределить метод hashCode(). Если метод equals() возвращает истину для двух объектов, то их хэш-код должен быть одинаковым. Обратное утверждение не верно.

```
TestClass {
    private int id;
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if(!super.equals(other)) return false;
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null) return false;
        if(this.getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;
        TestClass otherObj = (TestClass)other;
        return this.id == otherObj.id;
    }
    public int hashCode()
    {   
        return 76+133*id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

[Основные принципы](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) при проектировании метода `equals`:

1. Рефлексивность: для любых не-null объектов x, `x.equals(x)` должен возвращать `true`.
2. Симметричность: для любых не-null объектов x и y, `x.equals(y)` должен возвращать `true`, если и только если `y.equals(x)` возвращает `true`.
3. Транзитивность: для любых не-null объектов x, y, и z, если x.equals(y) возвращает `true` и `y.equals(z)` возвращает `true`, тогда `x.equals(z)` должен возвращать `true`.
4. Постоянство: повторный вызов метода `equals()` должен возвращать одно и тоже значение до тех пор, пока какое-либо значение свойств объекта не будет изменено. То есть, если два объекта равны, то они будут равны пока их свойства остаются неизменными.
5. Для любых не-null объектов x, `x.equals(null)` должно возвращать `false`.

Также стоит обратить внимание на то, что аргументом метода `equals` **всегда** является объект класса `Object`. Например, переопределяя метод для класса `Person`, мы должны использовать следующую сигнатуру: `public boolean equals(Object person)`. Зачастую начинающими допускается ошибка и используется сигнатура `public boolean equals(Person person)`, что приводит к перегрузке метода `equals`.

Метод `equals` взаимосвязан с методом `hashCode`: для одинаковых объектов значение, возвращаемое методом `hashCode`, должно быть одинаково. Поэтому зачастую переопределяются оба метода.

Answer (score 5):

Имеем простой класс такой структуры:

```
class A {
    final B someNonNullField;
    C someOtherField;
    int someNonStateField;
  }
```

Такой метод определения метода equals будет подойдет во многих ситуациях:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // Не строго необходимо, но обычно неплохо для оптимизации
    if (this == other)
      return true;
    if (!(other instanceof A))
      return false;
    A otherA = (A) other;
    return 
      (someNonNullField.equals(otherA.someNonNullField))
        && ((someOtherField == null) 
            ? otherA.someOtherField == null 
            : someOtherField.equals(otherA.someOtherField)));
  }
```

Действительно нельзя забывать о методе hashCode. сойдет такая его реализация:

```
public int hashCode() { 
    int hash = 1;
    hash = hash * 31 + someNonNullField.hashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 
                + (someOtherField == null ? 0 : someOtherField.hashCode());
    return hash;
  }
```

Более подробно написано с этой [статье](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html) от ibm deweloperworks.

Answer (score 4):

Прошу пояснить код. В частности, вот эту строку

```
if (!super.equals(other)) return false;
```

Основной вопрос состоит в следующем. Как Вы думаете, что делает эта строчка процитированного кода? Да, там вызывается метод equals родительского класса. А кто у нас у класса в данном случае родитель? Если верить спецификации, то это java.lang.Object. Значит сначала мы в первой строке Вашего кода вызываем метод equals класса Object. Как Вы думаете, что он делает? Вроде как это известная информация, но для большей достоверности вот цитата из исходников

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

То есть он возвращает true только в том случае, когда у нас ссылки на объект совпадают. Если же у нас 2 отдельных объекта, которые хранятся в памяти в разных местах (пусть у них содержимое одинаковое), ссылки на них не совпадают! А что это значит? Это значит, что благодаря строке `if(!super.equals(other)) return false;` Ваш метод `equals` будет возвращать `true`, только если мы будем сравнивать объект сам с собой! Наверное, это не то, чего бы всем хотелось, не так ли?
Думаю, эту строку надо убрать и тогда это будет больше похоже на правду. Но вообще каждый раз при написании своего equals надо принимать во внимание тот факт, что когда-то создатели `Java` и класса `java.lang.Object` в частности написали условия, которым должен удовлетворять переопределённый метод equals, найти их можно в исходниках, либо [здесь](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

И ещё заметка относительно `hashCode`. Вы упомянули только одно из требований котракта по `hashCode`: если 2 объекта считаются равными (equals возвращает true), то hashCode для них должен возвращать одинаковое значение. Дальше

> Обратное утверждение не верно.

на самом деле в контракте, найти можно - [здесь](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) стоит продолжение: "However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables". То есть надо принимать этот факт во внимание, как и ещё один пункт из этого же контракта.

Comment: Однако, если мы сравниваем объект сам с собой, очевидно, что equals() должен возвращать true. И если дальше идёт какой-то сложный и большой код, то весьма полезно оставлять эту строку, чтобы если вдруг получится, что мы сравниваем объект сам с собой, не выполнять дополнительной работы. Это в общем случае.

Кроме того, в большинстве прикладных случаев super всё-таки не Object. И мы не всегда знаем, какие там могут проходить проверки, поэтому такая строка тоже может оказаться полезной.

Ну и лично моё мнение, выполнять сначала сравнение для родительских объектов это просто хороший тон :)

Comment: Хотя, конечно следующая строчка, в которой проводится та же проверка, уже не нужна, потому что всегда следует иметь в виду, что какой бы ни был родительский класс, конец иерархии - Object, в котором эта проверка уже произведена.

Comment: Относительно сравнения для родительских объектов согласен. Но при этом надо понимать когда в роли родительского объекта выступает Object, для которого сравнение определяется лишь по ссылке, а когда действительно сравниваются объекты. Сейчас опубликовал вариант использования equals при наследовании - см пост, в комментах код плохо отображается

Comment: Мне кажется, вызов супер тут не нужен. Обычно я генерю equals and hashcode методы с помощью акшена в Идее - Alt+Insert, там тоже нет вызова супер

Comment: Ну у нас в конторе считалось, что это улучшает читаемость кода :)

Comment: Это конечно может зависеть от настроек ide, но Вы попробуйте сначала сгенерить метод equals для базового класса, а потом для дочернего. В этом случае наверняка увидите вызов super. Eclipse так делает. Тем не менее давайте лучше абстрагироваться от ide и писать/генерить с её помощью только тот код, который мы можем адекватно объяснить. Всё-таки концепцию повтороного использования кода никто не отменял

Comment: @Serg В следующий раз можете отредактировать свой удаленный ответ и восстановить, вместо того, чтоб другой плодить ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Вариант использования equals при наследовании. Пусть есть класс точка

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        // проверка на случай, если сравнение с самим собой
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (obj.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
            Point point = (Point) obj;
            if (point.x == this.x && point.y == this.y)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Теперь пришла в голову мысль написать расширение Point3D и для него также переопределить метод equals

```
public class Point3D extends Point {
    private int z;

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (super.equals(obj)) {
            /*
             * строки не нужны: эти проверки выполняется в базовом классе
             * if (this == other) return true; 
             * if (other == null) return false;
             * if(this.getClass() != other.getClass()) return false; 
             */
            Point3D p3d = (Point3D) obj;
            if (p3d.z == this.z)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```