# java приведение к другим классам

Tags: java, классы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на сколько плохая операция приведения к другому классу. Например, я переопределяю метод equals и хочу обратиться к полям класса, чтобы сравнить из, что лучшее сделать: методы get или привести к классу? На сколько операция приведения дорогая. Заранее спасибо!

```
public boolean equals(Object expression) {
        if (this == expression) return true;
        if (!(expression instanceof GeneralInterface)) return false;
        if (getClass() != expression.getClass()) return false;
        AbstractBinaryOperations binary = (AbstractBinaryOperations) expression;
        return arg1.equals(binary.arg1) && arg2.equals(binary.arg2);
    }
```

Comment: Честно говоря, у вас нет выбора. В том или ином виде приведение неизбежно.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "методами get" в качестве альтернативы приведению?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю можно написать, метод getLeft, который будет возвращать return args1. Аналогично getRight -> return args2. Просто как будто вызвать метод менее затратно, чем приводить к другому классу

Comment: А у кого вызывать-то? Объект, с которым происходит сравнение, без приведения имеет класс `Object`. Если его не приводить к нужному классу, то у него можно будет вызывать только методы класса `Object`

Comment: Я даже задумался как моя программа работает:) У меня есть абстрактный класс, который реализует интерфейс Expression, абстрактном классе есть метод equals. От этого класса наследуются 4 других: Add, Substract, Multiply, Divide. Я хочу уметь сравнивать выражения составленный из этих классов. На вход мне нужно получать именно Objaect(для тестов надо), затем через instanceof я проверяю реализует ли класс интерфейс соответственно я могу вызвать метод get, который есть в интерфейсе. Вот в таком случае, что лучшее get или привести?

Comment: Но ведь вы не сможете вызвать этот метод, если не приведёте `Object` к типу интерфейса) То есть, ну вот вы например сравнили по `instanceof`, и да, оказалось, что переданный объект имплементит нужный интерфейс. И как дальше вы планируете вызвать метод, не приводя `Object`?)

Comment: Если вы переопределяете метод 'equals' в своём классе, чтобы сравнивать по полям, то приведение типов неизбежно.  Другое дело, что в вашем случае переопределение выполнено немного странно (см. [Как правильно переопределить метод `equals()` в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439/)): 1) смешивается проверка `instanceof Interface` и равенство `getClass()`, которое будет истинным только для одинаковых подклассов 2) проверяются аргументы только на уровне родительского класса. 3) для коммутативных операций порядок аргументов _не обязательно важен_, а здесь получится `1+2 != 2+1`

Comment: Да, действительно без приведения наверно не получиться:( Большое всем спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте наследование, чтобы иметь иерархию объектов, тогда вы сможете вызывать геттеры, не задумываясь о приведении типов.

```
public boolean equals(Object expression) {
    if (this == expression) return true;
    if (!(expression instanceof GeneralInterface)) return false;
    GeneralInterface binary = (GeneralInterface) expression;
    return arg1.equals(binary.getArg1()) && arg2.equals(binary.getArg2());
}
```

Унаследуйте `AbstractBinaryOperations` от `GeneralInterface` (ну или имплементируйте общие методы - тогда Вы сможете обратиться к геттерам и не тратить ресурсы на кастинг.